# Woocommerce disable place order button for product with specific category and shipping zone

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce, shopping-cart

I am trying to disable the place order button and make a conditional message that is gonna be displayed at the cart and checkout page when:

A) the customer chooses to buy an item from a specific category of products (example: phones)

and

B) his address is in a specific shipping zone (example: Zone 4)

**Update**:

So after a lot of research around blogs and stack, i found a solution for the zone lock.

Although, Now i am facing 1 major issue which i cant fix because my PHP skills are bad and its my first time coding for WooCommerce in general.
So again i would really appreciate the help guys!

I need this code to make also a check for the specific product category (example phones) alongside the other pieces of code, because i need it all-together  to disable the order button and give a message when this conditions are meet.

If i remove $category = 'phones'; and the && has_term( $category, 'product_cat', $product_id ) the code works perfect only for the zone lock.

This is the code:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_order_button_html', 'disable_button' );
function disable_button( $button ) {
    $targeted_zone_name = "Zone 4";
    $category = 'phones';

    $chosen_shipping_methods = WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' );
    $chosen_shipping_method  = reset($chosen_shipping_methods);
    $chosen_shipping_method  = explode(':', $chosen_shipping_method );
    $chosen_shipping_zone    = WC_Shipping_Zones::get_zone_by( 'instance_id', end($chosen_shipping_method) );

    if( $targeted_zone_name == $chosen_shipping_zone->get_zone_name() && has_term( $category, 'product_cat', $product_id )) {
        $style  = 'style="background:Silver !important; color:white !important; cursor: not-allowed !important; text-align:center;"';
        $text   = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_button_text', __( 'Place order', 'woocommerce' ) );
        $button = '<a class="button" '.$style.'>' . $text . '</a>';
        wc_add_notice( sprintf( __('<strong>Error:</strong> Sorry we dont ship this product to your Zone. Please remove the item from the cart in order to checkout <a href="%s" class="button alt">My Cart</a>'),get_permalink(get_option('woocommerce_cart_page_id') ) ), 'notice' );
        
    }
    return $button;
}
```

Comment: Please fix the if statement and add the error/exception you got to question.

Comment: Hi! I made an update, i don't know if it helps you understand my problem any better. Sorry i did PHP only at school for a semester and i lack a lot of knowledge. I started coding last year and working with worpress in general. Although Thanks a lot for your suggestions!